# Allow ports on EC2 only for Heroku

Tags: amazon-ec2, heroku

I have some services - mysql, some HTTP services - which I would like to have open for Heroku exclusively. I can define IP adress / IP mask (I am not sure what it is in EC2 security groups). Which IP or mask fits only Heroku? I guess Heroku has more IPs it can possibly access my EC2 instance from.

How can I allow access to some EC2 ports only for Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

As described in Heroku's devcenter, to open your EC2 server to Heroku you can use the command:

```
$ ec2-authorize YOURGROUP -P tcp -p 3306 -u 098166147350 -o default
```

This will create a rule in the security group `YOURGROUP` from Heroku that will allow Heroku to connect to your server through `TCP port 3306`.

When connecting from the Heroku App to the EC2 server, instead of using the elastic IP, you should use the full public DNS record: `ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com`.

Sources:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/external-services

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=209565

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8638281/556413

Comment: Just wanted to add that Heroku no longer recommends using the account ID and security group name as a mechanism for granting access. See this changelog item for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/353

Answer (score 1):

I've asked the same question to Heroku support. They said to use the same configuration used for Amazon RDS.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon_rds

Comment: This answer doesn't seem quite relevant to me. The OP asks what block of IP addresses Heroku uses such that he can filter incoming connections to a variety of his own services.