# Elasticsearch on EC2, webserver on Heroku // EC2 ports only accessible from Heroku

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, heroku, elasticsearch

I have an instance of Elasticsearch facing the internet on an EC2.
On the other hand I have my webservice as a Heroku app.

I want to secure the Elasticsearch instance and allow inbound traffic only from my Heroku app.

I have found this [Elasticsearch plugin](https://github.com/salyh/elasticsearch-security-plugin) but it looks a bit painful. So what can be the best way to secure an open `xx.xx.xx.xx:9200` port of my EC2 instance facing the internet and connect to Heroku?

Is SSL a solution? I have little knowledge.

In Heroku I use python.

Similar questions: [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/211244/allow-ports-on-ec2-only-for-heroku) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636835/security-settings-between-amazon-ec2-instance-and-heroku/8638281#8638281) have an old solution which [Heroku does not recommend anymore](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/353). Another option is to move the webservice to AWS and secure it behind a firewall but, for the time, I prefer to let Heroku do the dev-ops.

Comment: In addition to the elasticsearch-security-plugin that you found, there is also https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty

Answer (score 0):

Because the heroku is cloud based, your heroku IP address is not static. A security group solution is not suitable here.
I would use SSL with some authentication (even HTTP authentication is enough IMHO, but I'm not a security expert).

If you want to go to the extreme, SSL with both server & client certificates is the way to go.

You could use nginx as a reverse proxy for elastic search, if it doesn't support the above features.